# How can I contribute to "build-dep python3" update?

Tags: package-management, python, compiling

In order compile cpython on Ubuntu,  I had to do

```
sudo apt-get build-dep python3
```

I found that it lacked many dependencies, and I want to contribute and enhancement to this. Where and how can I contribute this enhancement to default ubuntu repos?

Specifically, I want to add these packages to that build-dep

```
libffi-dev
libbz2-dev
libssl-dev
libsqlite3-dev
liblzma-dev
libreadline-dev
libgdbm-dev
libgdbm-compat-dev
tk-dev
```

Comment: You will get some pretty serious pushback on that from the maintainers, since Ubuntu's philosophy is to ship the base py3 in a couple packages (lib, minimal, common), and all the add-ons in other packages. Feel free to open a thread at http://discourse.ubuntu.com or send an e-mail to the ubuntu-dev mailing list to reach the Python maintainers.